# NetBeans IDE and project setup

Tags: php, html, netbeans

I set-up three projects in NetBeans IDE, two are html projects and another one is php project.

When I test run, the project php's index.php (Main home page) is wanted to be loaded first. Then it will load another index.html files (two sub pages).

But now when I run, the first html project's index.html is always loaded first since it is at the first position at IDE because of alphabetical order in project name.

How can I load php project's index.php file?

Comment: Have you tried setting up the main project? Right click on left pane (Projects) blank space?

Comment: @DenisSolakovic Yes I did like that. I setup php project first for example Black. Then followed by Test (html project). Still ok, index.php still loaded first. Then when I addin Admin(another html project). index.php is not loaded anymore. Then Admin's index.html is loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create project on NetBeans, you can specify the URL of project in the "Project URL" field.
Please see the below screenshots that will help you.

[Screenshot : Here you can see "Project URL" field, with the help of this you can specify you project's index.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSvim.png)

Comment: Yes the problem is that I have three projects, so there are three project urls.

Comment: You should setup all three projects separately, so you will have option to set each project's index.php separately.